# Nosql design - tags and mvc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, tags, mongoid

I'm using Rails and Mongoid. I'm trying to come up with a tagging feature (similar to stackoverflow in that each user can have "favorite" tags).

From the design articles I've read about mongodb, I've understood that I need to stop thinking in "4th normal" form. I keep thinking to have a many to many table with `tag_id` and `user_id` and another many to many table with `tag_id` and `item_id`. But from reading about nosql, it seems like it'd be much better to embed the tags (either as tags or even an array of strings) within each user or item.

There's going to be a list of tags in the "tags" collection and the application will control whether a user can add a tag to their favorites or not.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Do I have the `tag` model have a `key` on the `title` and just store an array of those `keys` in a user model? Would "linking" or "embedding" be better in this situation? I'm trying to think of how I'll retrieve the tags since they have a key such as `foo-bar` and the title is `Foo Bar`. If I need to retrieve the user's tags then do I need to loop through the array and fetch each tag model to get the titles?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you on the Ruby aspects of this, but here are some options on the MongoDB side..

You could create a tags collection with entries looking a bit like this: `{_id: ObjectId(), title: "Foo Bar"}`. Each user could then have an array of id values of the tags he subscribes too:

```
{ username: ...,
  tags: [ObjectId(), ObjectId(), ... ]}
```

You could then retrieve the the titles of a users tags using the $in operator:

```
db.tags.find({_id: { $in: [array from user] }});
```